# submit form with drowpdownlist

Tags: php, yii

In my app I had form and visitors can select any city to go to another page related to selected value .

So I created my code , but the problem data not sent .

Data is city id , I tested it in tamper data and no data sent , how to fix that and send data in get method

Model:

```
public function events_by_city(){
   return CHtml::listData(Events::model()->findAll("start >=now()  and active=1"),'city','city0.ecity'); 
}
```

Controller :

```
//////// start upcoming related to city 
 public function actionUpcomingcity(){
    if(isset($_GET['city'])){  
       $city=intval($_GET['city']);
       $courses=Courses::model()->findAll(" course_id in (select course_id from ict_events where start >=now() and city=$city and active=1 ) ",array('distinct'=>true,
    ));  

    $this->pageTitle=" Events";
    $this->layout='rsidebar';

    $this->render('upcoming_by_city',array('courses'=>$courses));
   }
   else{
     echo " No number   ";
   }
}
```

View :

```
<?php

  CHtml::form();

  $model= new Events;
  echo  chtml::activeDropDownList($model,'city',$model->events_by_city(),array('prompt'=>'استعراض الأحداث التدريبية ',"submit"=>array("site/upcomingcity",'city'=>$model->city))); 
  CHtml::endForm();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `"submit"=>array("site/upcomingcity",'city'=>$model->city)` is not correct. Try

```
'submit'=>('site/upcomingcity')
```

instead.